# Energy loss due to Cherenkov radiation

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, dissipation, cherenkov-radiation

I'm trying to find a formula for (or some sort of direction towards approximating) the energy lost by a ultra relativistic positron when traveling through a cherenkov detector but I can't seem to find anything

Comment: May be   Frank–Tamm formula  help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Tamm_formula

Comment: Thanks you that's what I was looking for